# Como operar datos en pyhon y sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Mi pregunta quizas sea bastante sencilla. Necesito hacer una suma de una columna de mi base de datos. El problema es que (de la forma que lo hago), me trae los datos como rows y no como int. Como hago para traer un dato de la base de datos tal cual es? 
Ejemplo:

```
def prueba():
    consulta= ("SELECT x from y")
    cur.execute(consulta)
    registros=cur.fetchall()
    for i in registros:
        print i
```

Entiendo que fetchall me muestra los datos como rows, pero de que forma lo traigo como un entero para poder operarlo? Espero haberme dado a entender, muchas gracias.

Comment: con `for i in registros` recuperas cada fila, para acceder a cada campo individualmente podrías acceder mediante un índice, por ej: `i[0]` para la primer columna de la fila.

Answer (score 0):

contador3 = resultadoconsolicitud.fetchall()

print(contador3)##=>imprimes el resultado de la consulta y te das cuenta la >>pocicion de tus datos

for row_number, row_data in enumerate(contador3): aqui recorres la lista

> > > dato1=int(row_data[0])
> > >
> > > dato2=int(row_data[1])
> > >
> > > dato3=int(row_data[2]) ya guardados en variables puedes operar con ellos